# Dealing with Data type Errors when creating New Indexed Fields - DAO MS Access - VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, indexing, dao, recordset

@HansUp, this is the full code that I needed.  My question was to ask whether I could create three New Fields. All three are built from fields - column data - from an existing TableX.

Field1 must be indexed while Field3 is a date. This date is the result of extracting a date from the string of another Field in the Table with a Right Expression.  It works, but as you can see, it's sketchy like a wobbly house built with popsicle sticks.  But it works...just don't blow on it.

```
Public Sub OrcleJEtoUnmatched() '---DONE---
Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld1 As DAO.Field, fld2 As DAO.Field, fld3 As DAO.Field
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim hertz As String, strpstn As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

'Copies table data from ORACLE JE Table; Creates / overwrites existing data to UNMATCHED Table (Working Table)
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT [Oracle JE].* INTO Unmatched FROM [Oracle JE];"

Set tdf = db.TableDefs("Unmatched")

With tdf
  Set fld1 = .CreateField("ID", dbText, 255)
  Set fld2 = .CreateField("BatchCalc", dbText, 255)
  Set fld3 = .CreateField("Vision Date", dbDate)

    .Fields.Append fld1
    .Fields.Append fld2
    .Fields.Append fld3
End With

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Unmatched", dbOpenTable)
Do Until rst.EOF
  hertz = rst![Accounting Document Item] & Mid(rst![JE Line Description], 20, 2) & Round(Abs(rst![Transaction Amount]), 0)
  rst.Edit
  rst!ID = Replace(hertz, " ", "") ' cleaning the string - spaces
  rst!ID = Replace(rst!ID, ")", "") ' cleaning the string - open paranths
  rst!BatchCalc = Mid(rst![JE Line Description], 8, 8) ' Extracting Date from current string in the Field 

  On Error Resume Next 'I had to do something to control the error where the string extracted doesn't equal a date like '12/30/15. This is cheap, I know. It should be something using if(vartype) <> vbdate then do something
  rst![Vision Date] = Right(rst![JE Line Description], 8)
  rst.Update
  rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close

DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ID ON Unmatched (ID) WITH PRIMARY"
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

Set fld1 = Nothing
Set fld2 = Nothing
Set fld3 = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking for a better way to deal with the `rst![Vision Date] =` line?  If yes, do something like `strVisionDate = Right(rst![JE Line Description], 8)`  Then if `IsDate(strVisionDate) = True` you can do `rst![Vision Date] = CDate(strVisionDate)`  That would leave `[Vision Date]` as Null when you don't have a valid date to store there.

Comment: @HansUp, Your solution is a cleaner code than mine.  Thank you, very much.  So, How much do I owe you?

Comment: Just the standard fee for Stack Overflow help --- nothing.  :-)